# Is there a way to declare a variable immutable in a meaningful way?

Tags: rust, immutability

Up until today, I thought declaring a variable without `mut` made sure it can not be changed after initialization.

I thought this was great because I always resented the way that `const` in C and C++ didn't guarantee anything.

I just found out I was wrong: Rust allows internal mutability (see [std::cell](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/)). It gives you some guarantees, but is not what I expect and wish for when I hear immutable.

Is there a way to declare something "really immutable"?

Comment: you can always use unsafe code to break any immutability guarantee, there's no way to get around that...

Comment: If you don't want interior mutability, what about simply not using types that provide it?

Comment: @Levans it might not be so trivial, maybe a type you are using is generic, and the user might plugin a type with interior mutability. Or you are using a type that has a private field with interior mutability... You might never know about that...

Comment: Rust does not really give strong mutability guarantees, it gives strong ownership guarantees (that in certain cases allow or prevent mutation as a by-product). In fact at one point there was [a discussion on modifying the language to make this focus on ownership more explicit](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/05/13/focusing-on-ownership/). This started the so-called "mutpocalypse", as a lot of people reacted strongly against it, so no changes were made.

Comment: @ker so only unsafe code can have interior mutability? Then i would consider any safe interface that uses unsafe code that does that as containing an error. Is there any sane argument to have it otherwise?

Comment: xophos: somewhere down the line unsafe code is required. Basically you can assume that any unsafe code doing interior mutability without using one of the `std::cell` or `std::sync` types is a bug or a misuse of some kind. The `*Cell` types specifically exist to allow interior mutability, you should not use unsafe to achieve the same

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by preventing mutability? I would be surprised if Rust doesn't handle the root problem that you are trying to address. Common things like *iterator invalidation* and *use-after-free* are handled quite nicely, even in the presence of mutability.

Comment: @Shepmaster the problem of hidden state for example.

Comment: When i declare something as immutable, i want to be sure that it will not change between initialization and destruction. If unsafe code can work around this, that is acceptable to me since unsafe code can by definition be used to break guarantees. But having something like that in the standard library is more than distasteful.

Comment: You know, types with internal mutability have some very good reason to exist. Patterns like `Arc<RwLock<_>>` are sometimes absolutely necessary. It would be quite horrible if it was not possible to use them in safe code...

Comment: Their role is mostly to ensure at runtime invariants that cannot be checked at compile-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preventing interior mutability is impossible in run-time evaluated code (Constant evaluation makes this easy, there's no mutation of any kind). Any type you use that you don't have control over might be using unsafe code to achieve interior mutability. To prevent the most common cases you can use a so called "marker trait". This trait has no other purpose but to allow you to differentiate between types that implement your trait and types that don't.

```
#![feature(optin_builtin_traits)]

use std::cell::{RefCell, Cell, UnsafeCell};
use std::sync::Mutex;

unsafe trait ReallyImmutable {}

unsafe impl ReallyImmutable for .. {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for RefCell<T> {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for Cell<T> {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for UnsafeCell<T> {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for Mutex<T> {}
impl<'a, T> !ReallyImmutable for &'a mut T {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for *mut T {}
impl<T> !ReallyImmutable for *const T {}
```

This has of course the disadvantage of requiring you to blacklist interior mutability instead of white-listing immutable types. So you might always miss something.

Comment: And there's the fact that you can convert `*const T` to `*mut T` and then mutate it that way. ^_^

Comment: as I said... it's not whitelisting, and in situations with unsafe code quite irrelevant anyway, so using the `*mut T` is already requiring unsafe... but yea... I missed that trivial one ^^ ... and you can go from a `&T` to a `*const T` and then we're back where we started... xD

Comment: Oh, I'm not trying to invalidate your answer in any way, just pointing out examples of how a malicious end user can subvert this, as you already mentioned was possible.